# How to close browser which is running a Vertex AI notebook, while keeping the notebook running and being able to come back to it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am using a Jupyter notebooks on GCP instances (Vertex AI).
Notebooks are hosted and executed on cloud e2e.
In case I am closing the browser tab, my computer falls to sleep, or even when I close it at the end of the day, I lose my work.
In case the product I need is stored in a variable, I can access it when I reload the notebook, but, many times the kernel dies. Even if it is not, for sure I am losing ALL the outputs which are printed to the notebook itself.

Is there any way to preserve them and the notebook state better?
I looked around in VertexAI documentation, asked GPT and searched Youtube, the only thing I found was detaching the notebook before closing the browser, BUT, this option is not available in the UI, I guess it was included in previous versions of the product.

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Some cells take a lot of time to run and I'm wondering if I can leave them running while closing my laptop.